# Node.js: Command line parsing with mutually exclusive arguments

Tags: node.js, command-line-arguments

I thought this should exist but it doesn't seem to be supported in any of the popular command line args parsing libraries.

I want my script to have a set of options that are exclusive of another option.

For example, here I use the `-c` option

```
$ node my_script.js -c "foo"
```

But here, the `-c` options doesn't make sense because I specified some different options.

```
$ node my_script.js -b "bar" -n 5
```

The following should be an error because `-c` is mutually exclusive to `-b` and `-n`

```
$ node my_script.js -b "bar" -n 5 -c "foo"
```

I know this exists in Python's argparse. I'm surprised I can't find it in the Node world.

Comment: How about just checking if `-b`, `-n` and `-c` are all set then just return an error? That looks pretty simple. Why does it have to be handled by the arg parsing library?

Comment: @MrJLP Because that was just a simple representative example

Comment: I agree with MrJLP, this is business logic, not parsing logic. But I also disagree that this should cause an error. The traditional way of handling this on unixen is to document that `-c is ignored if -b is specified` and just tell the user to read the man page

Answer (score 2):

[Commander.js](https://github.com/tj/commander.js/blob/master/examples/options-conflicts.js) has a convenient way of doing this through the `Option.conflicts` method. See the following example (adapted from [here](https://github.com/tj/commander.js/blob/master/examples/options-conflicts.js)):

```
const { program, Option } = require('commander');
program
  .addOption(new Option('--cash').conflicts('credit'))
  .addOption(new Option('--credit'));
```

If you attempt to use both arguments, the program will fail and output the following message: `error: option '--cash' cannot be used with option '--credit'`